# What is the fastest way to implement my interrupt?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, cortex-m

I have an external interrupt (running on an STM32F031K6). I want it to run as quick as possible - ideally inside 1uS. at the moment it runs in about 2.2uS. The interrupt is as follows

```
void EXTI4_15_IRQHandler(void)
{

    if (ChangeFlag & 1<<3){
        GPIOA->BSRR |= (1<<4);}
    else
        GPIOA->BSRR |= (1<<20);

    ChangeFlag |= 1<<1;

    if (ChangeFlag & 1<<2)
    {
        GPIOA->BSRR |= (1<<12);}
    else
        GPIOA->BSRR |= (1<<28);

    ChangeFlag |= 1<<0;

    EXTI->PR |= 1<<11; //turn off interrupt request
}
```

in particular the commands like GPIOA->BSRR |= (1<<12); are actually quite complex in the disassembly. Is there a way I can make them simpler?

Comment: what compilation optimisation level are you using ?

Comment: It isn't possible to answer the question in a sensible way without knowing the type of `ChangeFlag`. Is it `uint8_t`, `uint32_t` or something else? Is it `volatile`?

Answer (score 3):

Your example is incomplete and I don't understand what ChangeFlag is supposed to do. In case ChangeFlag is a volatile global there would be some optimization potential there...

What I can tell you though is that BSRR is a write-only register and read-write modifying it makes no sense.

[image: BSRR register]

Just replacing the |= operator with a simple assignment = will get rid of a couple of assembler instructions.

Answer (score 2):

By generating a mask, and then doing a single write to `GPIOA->BSRR` you will save a number of memory accesses

```
void EXTI4_15_IRQHandler(void)
{
    uint32_t mask = 0;
    if (ChangeFlag & 1<<3)
        mask = (1<<4);
    else
        mask = (1<<20);

    if (ChangeFlag & 1<<2)
        mask |= (1<<12);
    else
        mask |= (1<<28);

    ChangeFlag |= (( 1 << 1 ) | (1 << 0));
    GPIOA->BSRR = mask;

    EXTI->PR |= 1<<11; //turn off interrupt request
}
```

As @Vinci says, there's no point in using the `|=` operator on `GPIOx->BSRR` as it's a write only register, performing a read-modify-write on it is just a waste of cycles.

If change flag is a volatile global then you may make a saving by copying it once, into a temporary and using that in your conditionals, you'd have to check the compiled output.

Your part is can run at up to 48 MHz, in 1 μs that gives you 48 clock cycles,  there are 16 cycles between the exception occurring and your code being run for pushing state to the stack, and the same for popping everything back off on exception exit, that is 32 cycles total for housekeeping, this brings you to ~666 ns before your exception handler does any work, to stay within your 1 μs budget you've only got 16 clock cycles for your handler code. I'm not sure 1 μs is feasible.